# kendo scheduler event template

Tags: kendo-scheduler

Hi I would like to add a Kendo ToolTip inside the kendo Scheduler event template. When ever i add any Html helper it throws invalid template error. I might be missing some the syntax.Can anyone suggest the way to do it?

`d.EventTemplate(
            "<div style='height: auto !important;'>"+
            "#=kendo.toString(start,'hh:mm')# #= kendo.toString(start,'tt')# @"+
            "<span style='font-size:smaller'>#= PickStopName# </span> " +
            "#@(Html.Kendo().Tooltip().For('#Scheduler').Width(250)"+
                  ".Content('# <div style='text-align:justify;'>" +
                     "<div>" +
                        "<h6> #= title# </h6>" +
                        "<h6> #= description# </h6>" +
                        "<h4> #= kendo.toString(start,'hh:mm')# </h4>" +
                     "</div>" +
                 "</div>)'#)#"+
                 "</div>"
               );`

Comment: Just to clarify, if you remove the "#@(Html.Kendo()... and subsequent lines, the template works correctly?  The problem may be you are trying to use a Razor method in an Event Template which is executed on the client-side.  Try switching to the HTML5 JS version for your tooltip and it may work.

Comment: yes. If I remove the tooltip the template is working fine. If I switch to HTML5 JS version the content of the tooltip is dependent on the data in the template. Is there any way i can get it to display tat content?

Comment: I used HTML5 JS version of Treeview and solved the issue.

Comment: @piercove Thank you for the hint. I added HTML5 JS version like this. 

`"<a href='javascript: void(0);'"+
"onmouseover = \" setToolTip('Task-#=kendo.toString(start, \'dd\')#','#= title#', '#= description#') \"> " +
"#= kendo.toString(start,'h:mm')# #= kendo.toString(start,'tt')# @ #=PickStopName#</a>"` 
`<script>
    function setTooltip(id, title, description) {
        var tooltip = $("#" + id).kendoTooltip(
        {
            width: 250,
            content: title + " - " + description
        }).data("kendoTooltip");
    }
</script>`